# Can you run unit tests with Quarkus without starting all dependencies?

Tags: java, unit-testing, quarkus

New to Quarkus and tried unit testing and it seems to take too long starting all the dependencies.
Previous projects used PowerMockRunner so it tested just the class i was working with, but preferably wanted to just use Quarkus dependencies/options and not introduce new one. How can i make it run faster or make it run just the class...cause is a unit test.

```
@QuarkusTest
public class ExampleTest {

@InjectMock
private Dependency dep;

@Inject
private MyCLass underTest;

@Test
public void testStuff() {
    underTest.doStuff();
    Mockito.verify(dep, Mockito.times(1)).doMoreStuff(Mockito.any());
}
}
```

Comment: When you say that it takes too long, can elaborate please?

Comment: Hi @geoand I think is the devservices that get started when running integration tests...like we have mssql in dependencies, and the docker container gets created and started when the test run.

Comment: For now to get around it: i ended up adding mockito to dependancies and replaced @QuarkusTest with @ExtendWith(MockitoExension.class)....that seem faster since only load and run one test at a time